# How to implement a long running background process to stream from an external server in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, background-process

I'm writing a simple stock & options portfolio management system in Rails 7 for my own use.

My broker offers a rudimentary api and some prices are streamed so I have to keep a long running background process going to read from the stream. But Rails is very much oriented towards request <==> response architecture and running a permanent process in the background that gets prices from the stream outside a request <==> response flow doesn't seem to fit.

I'm puzzling how to do this, running an ActiveJob doesn't seem to be the right thing because that's set up to do one job and then finish, not keep open a stream from an external server.

I could have a Rake task running in the background, but that seems very inelegant.

The other option is to switch to writing the whole thing in Elixir which can handle long running background processes with ease. But I don't know much about Elixir, though I could get ChatGPT & CoPilot to help me transfer existing work over from Rails.

Another option is to have a completely separate process, written in any language, which pulls data from the stream and then pushes it to the Rails app via the default api.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how this can be done in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely use a rake task, or a [Rails runner](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner). You might also like the option of [using your own Railtie](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) with a `server` block that forks or runs in its own thread.

Comment: Rails runner seems to be the best option. Thanks